# How to read in a file and output the file with the same file name into another subfolder using pathlib.Path().glob()

Tags: python, pandas, glob, pathlib

How do I read in files and output the files with the same file names into another subfolder using `pathlib.Path().glob()`?

My directory looks like this:

```
New Folder 1

-> p1_a.csv

-> p1_b.csv

-> New Folder 2
```

Code:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

file_path = r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\New Folder 1'

for fle in Path(file_path).glob('p1_*.csv'):
   df = pd.read_csv(fle)

   # do something with df

   df.to_excel(file_path + r'\New Folder 2' + 'p1_*.csv' + '_new.csv')
```

The bit of the code which I am not sure about is `'p1_*.csv'`.

After the code is run, my directory should look like this:

```
New Folder 1

-> p1_a.csv

-> p1_b.csv

-> New Folder 2

-> -> p1_a.csv_new.csv

-> -> p1_b.csv_new.csv
```

What do I need to have in the `'p1_*.csv'` bit so that the new files copied in New Folder 2 has part of the same file names as the original file?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

source_dir = r'C:/Users/HP/Desktop/New Folder 1'

for path in Path(source_dir).glob('p1_*.csv'):
   df = pd.read_csv(path)
   # TODO: do something with df

   filename = os.path.basename(path) #--> gets the file name
   dest_path = os.path.join(source_dir, "New Folder 2", f"{filename}_new.csv")

   df.to_csv(dest_path)
```

*Now your directory structure will look like:*

```
New Folder 1
├── New Folder 2
│   ├── p1_a.csv_new.csv
│   └── p1_b.csv_new.csv
├── p1_a.csv
└── p1_b.csv
```

Comment: Many thanks for this! Can I ask what does the f”...” do?

Comment: Its a fstring. For example if `a=2 `then `f"{a} apples"` will result in `2 apples`. You can learn more about fstrings at [fstrings in python](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

Answer (score 2):

Essentially the same as Shubham's, without calling the os module:

```
for fle in Path(file_path).glob('p1_*.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(fle)

   # do something with df
   new_location = Path(file_path).parent.joinpath('New Folder 2', f'{fle}_new.csv')
   df.to_excel(new_location)
```